# Query with range returning empty

Tags: jquery, sql, json, soql

I'm building a simple query to recover some data based on the creation date of the record:

```
function buildQuery(startDate, endDate)
{
    var start_date = formattedDate(startDate);  //YYYY-MM-DD
    var end_date = formattedDate(endDate);      //YYYY-MM-DD
    var c_type = 'Noise';                                          // Complaint Type

    // Build the data URL
    URL = "http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/erm2-nwe9.json"; // API Access Endpoint
    URL += "?";                                                   // A query parameter name is preceded by the question mark
    URL += "$where=";                                             // Filters to be applied
    URL += "(latitude IS NOT NULL)";                              // Only return records with coordinates
    URL += " AND ";
    URL += "(complaint_type='" + c_type + "')";                    // Desired complaint
    URL += " AND ";
    URL += "(created_date>='" + start_date + "') AND (created_date<='" + end_date + "')"; // Date range
    URL += "&$group=complaint_type,descriptor,latitude,longitude";                        // Fields to group by
    URL += "&$select=descriptor,latitude,longitude,complaint_type";                       // Fields to return
    URL = encodeURI(URL);                                                                 // Encode special characters such as spaces and quotes
}
```

When I used startDate = endDate, no matter what date it is, the result **.json**, that I obtain using the following code, returns empty.

```
$.getJSON(URL, function(data)
```

However, if I check:

> http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/erm2-nwe9.json

there is records that match the specific date. 
For example, this occurs when startDate and endDate are both equal to 2015-11-29.

Comment: The created_date probably has a time component. In which case, if start and end are both equal to 2015-11-29, then you would only get records created exactly at midnight on that date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rabbit appears to be right - the returned data contains `"created_date" : "2015-11-30T02:14:24"` indicating that the "date" has a time component. Change these two lines of your code:

```
var start_date = formattedDate(startDate)+"T00:00:00";  //YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss
var end_date = formattedDate(endDate)+"T23:59:59";      //YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss
```